# Trigger for IsMouseOver on TabItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have some issues with my `TabItem` style. Here is the style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="160"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="70"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <Border Name="Border" Background="Transparent">

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    Margin="10,2"/>

                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem is that the `IsMouseOver` event is triggered also by moving above any of its child item.
I've added the `SourceName="ContentSite"` to the Trigger:

```
<Trigger SourceName="ContentSite" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
```

With this code the IsMouseOver is no longer triggered by moving around child elements but it introduced another problem. The IsMouseOver event is triggered only when the cursor is over the header of the tabitem. The same issue was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569131/trigger-for-ismouseover-on-tabitem-contentemplate) by another user. The proposed answer was to add the Background="Transparent" value to the Border, but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: When shall IsMouseOver be triggered then if you dont want it at Headers and at children elements? What is left then? Thats all a TabItem has. :)

Comment: Do you want the event to be triggered only on tab headers or just content or both?

Comment: I want the event to be triggered only on tab header. By adding the SourceName="ContentSite" the event is triggered _only_ when the cursor is over the TextBlock inside TabItem.Header.

Comment: I want the event to be triggered when the cursor is over the whole TabItem's area 160x70, not only when it is over the TextBlock inside header. I hope this clarifies the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, All you have to do is Changing `SourceName` on `Trigger` to Border from `ContentSite`.

Please try the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="160"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="70"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <Border Name="Border" Background="Transparent">

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    Margin="10,2"/>

                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" SourceName="Border">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And, if you want that to happen only for non selected tabs, you can try the below `MultiTrigger`

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" SourceName="Border" Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
</MultiTrigger>
```